# How to get number of occurrence of character in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

in open column `~` is present I want to filter the  records which as more than 4  `~` occurance in open column.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you improve your question,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)
Don't add the code as a picture, add it in the question itself

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: If the answer helped you, mark the answer and upvote please

Answer (score 0):

you could just count for the occurrences of a character in a string as follows

```
select *
  from your_table
 where length(open)-length(replace(open,'~',''))>4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where open like '%~%~%~%~%~%'
```